# How to Differentiate mobile data used among the sims in a dual sim?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to measure mobile data used by different SIM cards in a multi SIM phone. Is there any way where I could programmatically get the data? Or Is there at least a way in which I could know on which SIM mobile data is turned on?